# Authentication and Authorisation Best Practice in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: authentication, authorization, blazor, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

I am about to embark on building a new online system with Blazor Webassembly (net 6.0) which will require users to log in before they can make use of any of the features.

I am currently trying to decide on the best approach to dealing with authentication and authorisation. Previously, when setting up a new Blazor project I have used the built in authentication by selecting the 'Individual User Accounts' option and then scaffolded the razor pages on the server project. I like this option because it uses IdentityServer and that feels like a safer option for me as I am certainly no expert on security. However, as part of this new system, certain users will need to be able to administrate other users within their own company and I don't really want to have to send them to the razor pages to do this as I'm using a component library (Radzen) on the client side and the look and feel will be inconsistent between client and server.

I've found a [great tutorial](https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/) from Chris Sainty that will enable me to set up authentication and authorisation myself, but I've got doubts over whether it will be secure enough if I go this route.

I guess the questions I have that will help me decide either way are:

1. Is it possible to use Blazor component libraries like Radzen on the ASP.NET Core hosted project?
2. If not, is it possible to create user management pages client side using Razor components and somehow get those to communicate with the set up server side? I will need admin users to be able to create, update and delete users.
3. Finally if the two options above aren't possible, is there anything in particular that I need to be considering when setting up authentication and authorisation myself to make sure that the system is as secure as possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You should not do any user management in your Blazor Web Assembly application.  It isn't secure - your entire application is downloaded to the browser, and anyone with a little knowledge can de-assemble your code.  My guess is the best solution is to build a separate User Management system as a Blazor Server Application.  You can then use the Radzen library to maintain the UX.  You can host Server and WASM Applications along side each other - see article - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5299017/Building-a-Blazor-WASM-and-Server-All-In-One-Solut

Comment: I would watch this before I do anything else https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2022/04/25/webinar-using-the-bff-pattern-to-secure-spa-and-blazor-applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use Blazor component libraries like Radzen on the ASP.NET Core hosted project?

Yes, you can embed Razor components in Razor Pages pages.

> is it possible to create user management pages client

Yes, it is... But then any security measure taken by you is rendered useless. Never do such a thing. Instead, create the user management pages on the Asp.Net Core Server project ( hosted, right ?), and navigate your users to these pages from Blazor pages. You may embed Radzen components (Razor components) in these pages.

> Finally if the two options above aren't possible, is there anything in particular that I need to be considering when setting up authentication and authorisation myself to make sure that the system is as secure as possible?

I wouldn't recommand choosing this path. It is hard, hazardous, and not effective. Use existing systems.

As far as I can understand your issue is the look of the UI, right ? In that case, you can scaffold pages such as the Login.cshtml and give them a look of a Radzen component. It's not hard to let the user believe he's navigating in the same web site. This is the way I recommand to do that. Or embed Radzen components in those pages, and make them communicate with each other.

### Simple example

Suppose you want the Login.cshtml to look as if it was a Radzen component, and Radzen suite contains a Login component ( I'm not familiar with those libraries). In that case, you should first scaffold the Login.cshtml page, and either embed the Radzen Login component in the Login Razor Pages page you've just scaffolded, or, this should be much much easier, just copy the CSS used in the Radzen Login component, and use it in your scaffolded Login page.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your advice. It's definitely the look of the UI that is causing me to pause. I will be using the Radzen datagrids and dropdowns quite heavily on the client side of the project and ideally I would also be able to use these server side (yes, it's ASP.NET Core hosted) for user management. These components are quite feature rich so I think it would be difficult to emulate them. Do you know of any good tutorials that might help me embed them into the Razor pages instead?

Comment: `many thanks for your advice.`  This is not an advice. This is an answer to your question, and should be treated so...upvoted, accepted, etc. `difficult to emulate them.` In that case I believe the best solution is to embed them in your Razor Pages App pages. I'm not aquianted with any tutorials regarding this, except the ones from the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#render-components-from-a-page-or-view).

Comment: Note that it may require some efforts and time on your part to do that, so consider whether it is worth the efforts involved (cost-effective). Personally , I would exert any efforts to do that. You may email me if you want me to send you a simple code of embedding a Razor component in a Razor Pages page.